Can we customize the styles of the npm packages in React project
Can we customize the styles of the npm packages after installing in our React project according to our needs, like changing colors, etc.?
I've installed a npm package which is rc-slider in my React project. Now I want to customise those sliders like colors and size according to my project needs. first I inspect those element and found their selectors classname after that in node modules directory there is rc-slider/assets/index.css. I tried changing the color and size of sliders but still changes are not reflecting in web page.

Do you really need to change styles in the npm package? Docs: https://barakplasma.github.io/slider/. There are APIs like className to change style of a root DOM node and handleStyle. I am not sure of course, never used this package

Anything you change in packages will be overwritten on the next update/install anyway. Use styling options from package APIs that I see in the documentation.

Just add your own CSS that loads later than theirs: done, your rules win. No need to change anything "in a package", just take advantage of how CSS has worked since the invention of CSS.
